# Why does append overwrite subelements?

Tags: go

I create this struct:

```
type Country struct {
Id              interface{} `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
Languages       []string    `json:"languages"`
Country         string      `json:"country"`
Country_id      int         `json:"country_id"`
Capital         string      `json:"capital"`
Currency_name   string      `json:"currency_name"`
Currency_symbol string      `json:"currency_symbol"`
Currency_code   string      `json:"currency_code"`
Iso             string      `json:"iso"`
```

}

Then from Mongo I get all the data that i need.The problem is when i try to append each element, the langueges are overwritting.

Here is the append:

```
func GetAllCountries() []models.Country { 
options := options.Find() options.SetLimit(4)

cur, err := db.Collection(COLLCOUNTRIES).Find(context.Background(), bson.D{}, options)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
var elements []models.Country
var elem models.Country
// Get the next result from the cursor
for cur.Next(context.Background()) {    
    err := cur.Decode(&elem)
            if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    elements = append(elements, elem)
}
if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
cur.Close(context.Background())

return elements
```

}

The result is like this:

-- element before append --

```
 {ObjectID("5d7f6b2b57d5104f58e53d2b") [ar-AE fa en hi ur] United Arab Emirates 290557 Abu Dhabi Dirham د.إ AED AE}
```

-- element before append --

```
{ObjectID("5d7f6b2b57d5104f58e53d2c") [fa-AF ps uz-AF tk] Afghanistan 1149361 Kabul Afghani ؋ AFN AF}
```

-- all the results --

```
[{ObjectID("5d7f6b2b57d5104f58e53d2b") [fa-AF ps uz-AF tk ur] United Arab Emirates 290557 Abu Dhabi Dirham د.إ AED AE} {ObjectID("5d7f6b2b57d5104f58e53d2c") [fa-AF ps uz-AF tk] Afghanistan 1149361 Kabul Afghani ؋ AFN AF}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration over the cursor you're reusing the same block of memory with `&` on the pre-declared `elem`, essentially overwriting the data decoded in the previous iteration. Instead, inside the loop, allocate a new elem for each record in the db.

For example:

```
var elements []models.Country

// Get the next result from the cursor
for cur.Next(context.Background()) {
    var elem models.Country
    if err := cur.Decode(&elem); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    elements = append(elements, elem)
}
```